# Can't access files uploaded through php

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, centos, file-permissions

I have a server hosted with A Small Orange, smallest plan, running CentOS 6.5 with cPanel and WHM. I have set up an account in WHM, and I was having problems being able to mkdir or upload files, which was resolved when I changed the PHP Handler on cPanel to suphp.

Files will upload now, but I can't access them when they are uploaded.

Running `whoami` from PHP prints the Website account users name (site1), who is also the owner of all files in that clients public_html folder.

I am getting the error below when trying to upload files, not sure where I am going wrong really

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /uploads/project/3/img.png on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: You might need to ask your host about this. I had a simular problem befor and asking the host solved it for me

Comment: Could be .htaccess issue or group to which your user belongs may not have permission.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your host like the people in the comments are suggesting. If your code is successfully uploading your files and you then get a permission error you will want to contact whoever managers your server.

Also, how are you accessing them?